# why different results using matrix to imageview vs bitmap?

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, android-bitmap

why using matrix with ImageView setImageMatrix(matrix) and 
Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.width(), bmp.height(), matrix, true);
give different results?

option 1.
using setImageMatrix(matrix); it works properly only I 
setLayoutParams(deviceWidth,deviceHeight);
it means the size of drawable  could be smaller than the the size of ImageView,as you can see the setBackgroundColor(Color.RED) paints the whole screen ,while I need ImageView with exact drawable sizes,but when I use setLayoutParams() with sizes appropriate bitmap size the bitmap is cropped 
you can see the image ,where I display ImageView with deviceSize-layoutParams and bitmapSize-layoutParams
this is my matrix 
 Matrix{[1.8266667, 0.0, 110.0][0.0, 1.3733333, 117.000015][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

```
private void drawBitmap() {
    imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(deviceWidth, deviceHeight));
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image4);

    Matrix matrix = loadMatrix(bmp);
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, deviceWidth, deviceHeight);
    RectF imageRect = new RectF(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
    matrix.setRectToRect(imageRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.START);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    setContentView(imageView);
}
```

I receive the result displayed on 2_nd part of the image,while need to have transformed ImageView like displayed on 1st part only without occupying the whole screen,while I get such result 
commenting this line 
 matrix.setRectToRect(imageRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.START);
        [image]

while using the 2_nd options there is no problems with layoutParams
while it somehow crop the ImageView and not display fully

matrix include data that should scale and translate  ImageView

I need one of the right solutions transformed ImageView with drawable size.I mean the ImageView should occupy (or the touch area of ImageView)should be as the drawable part.

```
   Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((source.getWidth()),
            (source.getHeight()),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setDither(true);
    p.setFilterBitmap(true);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
    matrix.mapRect(rectF);

    targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) rectF.width(), (int) rectF.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, p);
    if (targetBitmap != source) {
        source.recycle();
    }
return targetBitmap;
```

Comment: Trying to understand.  wrap_content means the ImageView will only be as big as the image, yet you are talking about scaling the image.  Please edit your question to talk more about what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  I have just recently been working a lot with scaling by matrix in ImageView, so pretty familiar with how that works.  One hint I can give you is to make sure that the ImageView has run onLayout(), otherwise the ImageView won't have a width and height that you need for setting up the matrix.

Comment: Suppose the ImageView was sized with match_parent, and your bitmap was set to a size that covered the whole ImageView, and you could zoom in, but when you zoomed out the bitmap would never get smaller than the ImageView, would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void drawBitmap() {

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image4);
    int imageWidth = bmp.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = bmp.getHeight();

    // first we set the size of the view to have the same aspect ratio
    // as the image
    int viewWidth = deviceWidth;
    int viewHeight = deviceWidth * imageHeight / imageWidth;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight));

    // imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    //  get a rectangle that is the size of the ImageView
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);

    // get a rectangle that is the size of the bitmap
    RectF imageRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    // init the matrix so it will map the image to the full size of the view
    // imageRect is the source rectangle, the current size of the image
    // viewRect is the target rectangle, the size we want the image to be
    // setRectToRect will calculate the matrix required to map source to target
    // we use scale to fit so that the aspect ratio doesn't change
    matrix.setRectToRect(imageRect, viewRect, ScaleToFit.START);

    // tell the ImageView to use this matrix
    // make sure android:scaleType="matrix" is in the ImageView attributes
    imageView.setMatrix(matrix)

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: Dear @kris larson I have edited my question and changed the screenshot
and I have used your posted code,but I couldn't get the right result.

Comment: it doesn't make any changes :(